# Backbone.js collection not fetching successful by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

So i have mongodb collection of attendees

```
_id
event_id
name
profile_picture
user_id
```

I am routing two GET attendees collection

```
app.get('/attendee', event.eventAttendee);
app.get('/attendee/:event_id', event.findAttendeeByEventId);
...
...
exports.findAttendeeByEventId = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.event_id;
    console.log('Retrieving attendee: ' + id);
    db.collection('attendees', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'event_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
            item.toArray(function(err, items){
                res.send(items);
            });
        });
    });
};

exports.eventAttendee = function(req, res) {
    res.send(200);
};
```

localhost:3000\attendee\528b4f85dafbffbc12000009 gives me something like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "528b8c15e639d70e484b65ac",
    "event_id": "528b4f85dafbffbc12000009",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "profile_picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/1205633679/picture",
    "user_id": "5289e8bbdc91fe1803000009"
  },
  {
    "_id": "528b8c58e639d70e484b65ad",
    "event_id": "528b4f85dafbffbc12000009",
    "name": "Mary Doe",
    "picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/100000484671087/picture",
    "user_id": "528a0b4e4833678c11000009"
  }
]
```

I created a Backbone Model class for attendee with collection

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap',
    'app/helpers/config'
], function(Backbone, config) {

        var Attendee = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: "/attendee",
            idAttribute: "event_id"
        });

        var AttendeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Attendee,
            url: "/attendee"
        });

        return {
                model: Attendee,
                collection: AttendeeCollection
        };    
});
```

Then a ListView Class to List all the Attendees. So there are two View here one is the list view and the other is the List View Item.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'backbone.listview',
], function($,
            _, 
            Backbone,
            ListView) 
    {
    var ListView = Backbone.ListView.extend({});

    var EventAttendeeListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "div",
        className: "dish col-md-4",
        initialize: function () {
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html('Name: ' + this.model.get('name'));
            return this;
        }
    });
    return{
        ListView: ListView,
        ListItemView: EventAttendeeListItemView
    };

});
```

I am rending this function in other file where EventAttendees points to the above view file

```
var attendee = new Attendee.collection({
    event_id: id
});

var listView = new EventAttendees.ListView({
  className: 'list',
  collection: attendee,
  itemView: EventAttendees.ListItemView
});

attendee.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log("listView.render().el");   
        console.log(listView.render().el);
    },
    error: function(){
       console.log("arguments"); 
       console.log(arguments); 
    }
});
```

The Problem is the collection is not fetch successful and hence below lines are not executed and i am getting an error --http://pastebin.com/HDaQaWcW(can someone also help how to find the make some sense of the error?)

```
    console.log("listView.render().el");   
    console.log(listView.render().el);
```

EDIT:
as per @homtg i got a new update.

I was getting an error because there was no json 
Its seems that my backbonejs is not doing localhost:3000\attendee\528b4f85dafbffbc12000009 insert doing a localhost:3000\attendee. 
**How do i tell the collection to fetch by event_id?**

Comment: are you sure the collection is not fetched, maybe you just do not have the success callback triggered, try adding an error callback to the fetch and check if this helps you and if there really is no fetch

Comment: @homtg Yes Its going to the error but i can't make out what the error is. I have updated the  question. Thanks again

Comment: try error: function(collection, response, options), and then log the response var to your console. Or look in the network monitor of your browser for the error.

Comment: @homtg Its seems that my backbonejs is not doing localhost:3000\attendee\528b4f85dafbffbc12000009 insert doing a localhost:3000\attendee. How do i tell the collection to fetch by event_id. I was getting an error because there was no json

Comment: do not forget up me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
idAttributemodel.idAttribute
```

A model's unique identifier is stored under the id attribute. If you're directly communicating with a backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that uses a different unique key, you may set a Model's idAttribute to transparently map from that key to id.

```
var Meal = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_id"
});

var cake = new Meal({ _id: 1, name: "Cake" });
alert("Cake id: " + cake.id);
```